# Oauth2: how should the resource server know if the access token is valid?

Tags: rest, authentication, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm implementing an Ouath2 authentication with Spring for our mobile API. So far it works but I don't know how I should keep the resource server separate. So I have an auth server which gives out tokens and refresh tokens using the password grant-type. Meaning the user would log into the mobile app, which sends the auth server the client id/client secret along with the user's 
credentials, which results in an access token and a refresh token for the user with the appropriate (ROLE_USER) privileges. Another web based client is for the admins who do the same and get the ROLE_ADMIN privilege etc.

This works well so far.

Now if any client sends a request to the **resource server** what should happen? Should the resource server check the token's validity? If so in what way? Or should the auth server copy the token into the resource-server's database?

Answer (score 2):

If you `@EnableResourceServer` you get a filter that checks access tokens. It needs to share a `TokenStore` with the auth server. That's about it to get something working.

Comment: Can you tell me which filter?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/authentication/OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java